# Parsing Email Headers Tabs

Tags: python, email

I am parsing E-Mails with the Python `email` module.

If I parse it with the Python E-Mail parser, it does not remove the tab in front of the header items:

```py
from email.parser import Parser
from email.policy import default

testmail = """Date: Wed, 26 Jan 2022 10:45:29 +0100
Message-ID:
    <123123123123123123123123123123123123123.testinst.themultiverse.com>
Subject:
    =?iso-8859-1?Q?Auftragsbest=E4tigung_blablabla?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?_one nice thing?=

Content Body Whatnot"""


message = Parser(policy=default).parsestr(testmail)

print(repr(message["Message-Id"]))
print(repr(message["Subject"]))
```

results in:

```
'\t<123123123123123123123123123123123123123.testinst.themultiverse.com>'
'\tAuftragsbestätigung blablabla one nice thing'
```

I have tried the different policies of the `email` parser, but I do not manage to remove the tab in the beginning. I saw the `header_source_parse` method of the `EmailPolicy` class does strip the whitespace, but only in combination with a space in the beginning.

`<pythonlib>/email/policy.py`:

```py
[...]
        value = value.lstrip(' \t') + ''.join(sourcelines[1:])
[...]
```

Not sure if that is intended behavior or a bug.

My question now: **Is there a way in the standard library to do this, or do I need to write a custom policy?** The E-Mails are unchanged from an IMAP Server (exchange) and it feels strange that the standard tools do not cover this.

Comment: Given the code excerpt, this definitely looks like a bug, though quick reading of RFC5322 did not clearly identify either behavior as definitely correct.

Comment: Interestingly enough this behaviour does not occur for the `Date` header that has no embedded newline...

Answer (score 1):

Something let me think that the message is not strictly conformant to RFC5322.

We can see at 3.2.2.  Folding White Space and Comments:

> However, where CFWS occurs in this specification, it MUST NOT
> be inserted in such a way that any line of a folded header field is
> made up entirely of WSP characters and nothing else.

But for the `Subject` and `Message-ID` fields, the first line will only contain spaces before the first newline.
IIUC, it correspond to an obsolete syntax, because we find at 4.  Obsolete Syntax:

> Another key difference between the obsolete and the current syntax is
> that the rule in section 3.2.2 regarding lines composed entirely of
> white space in comments and folding white space does not apply.

The doc for EmailPolicy from Python Standard Library is even more explicit on what happens:

> **header_source_parse**(*sourcelines*)
>
> The name is parsed as everything up to the ‘:’ and returned unmodified. The value is determined by **stripping leading whitespace off the remainder of the first line**, joining all subsequent lines together, and stripping any trailing carriage return or linefeed characters.

As the tab occurs on the second line, it is not stripped.

I am unsure whether this interpretation is correct, but a possible workaround is to specialize a subclass or `EmailPolicy` to strip that initial line:

```
class ObsoletePolicy(email.policy.EmailPolicy):
    def header_source_parse(self, sourcelines):
        header, value = super().header_source_parse(sourcelines)
        value = value.lstrip(' \t\r\n')
        return header, value
```

If you use:

```
message = Parser(policy=ObsoletePolicy()).parsestr(testmail)
```

you will now get for `print(repr(message['Subject']))`:

```
'Auftragsbestätigung blablabla one nice thing'
```

Comment: But the `headername:` keyword is not CFWS so the line is not empty.

Comment: @tripleee: That is the reason why I said that *I am unsure whether this interpretation is correct*. Nevertheless is is the interpretation of the Standard Library...